# Forbidding a certain url from being scraped

Tags: python, scrapy

For some reason, a certain mobile url is being crawled and the resulting url is giving an error on being scraped. I want scrapy to just ignore the url and don't call parse method or anything on it.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    # name, allowed_domains etc
    rules = Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(deny=r'/m/.+') # deny http://example.com/m/anything-here.html
```

but this is not working and such links are still getting crawled.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml):

> `deny` (a regular expression (or list of)) – a single regular expression (or list of regular expressions) that the (absolute) urls must match in order to be excluded (ie. not extracted).

And `/m/.+` won't match an absolute URL like `http://example.com/m/anything-here.html`. For the same reason you need the `.+` on the end, you need at least a `.*` on the beginning:

```
>>> print(re.match(r'/m/.+', 'http://example.com/m/anything-here.html'))
None
>>> print(re.match(r'.*/m/.+', 'http://example.com/m/anything-here.html'))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 39), match='http://example.com/m/anything-here.html'>
```

Comment: If he wants to deny just the domain in question, a better expression would be `http://example.com/m/.+`, because he maybe still wants to scrape others like `http://test.com/m/something.html`.

Comment: @Lawrence: Sure, but given the way his question is written, and the fact that he _tried_ to write it with just `/m/.+`, I'm pretty sure he wants to deny either (1) any URL with `/m/` in it, or (2) any URL where the path component starts with `/m/`, not a specific domain.